# Emacs. Testing some configurations

Tags: emacs

What is the best way to try some confirgures with Emacs(for instatce [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) and [emacs-live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live))

1. To have such structure ~/.emacs-prelude, ~/.emacs.d-prelude and ~/.emacs-live, ~/.emacs.d-live. And remove appropriate suffix, every tive when I whant to try some config. I can make script for fast renaming, depending on passed options.
2. To have only "init" files separated(~/.emacs-prelude and ~/.emacs-live) and ~/.emacs.d - in common, so I can start emacs -q -l ~/.emacs-prelude.el . But I have to merge my .emacs.d dirs from both before. Not sure about conflicts in this case...

So, my goal is to achieve something like this: emacs-start --live(--prelude) ....

P.S. Should I deal with site-file? What if I want to save bookmarks and use them with both configurations?...

Answer (score 2):

The best way to change emacs configurations is to use symbolic links for `.emacs` and `.emacs.d/`. Just point them to the configuration you are currently interested in.

Using links, you can also share things like bookmarks between configurations.